# EAS Build Android Manifest Provider Authority Conflict

Tags: expo, google-play, eas

When uploading my AAB bundle generated from an EAS Build I receive this error:

Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.app.p1591CD.firebaseinitprovider.

I generated an Android.Manifest.xml after reading this [post](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/233249351/unable-to-upload-new-build?hl=en), but my file does not contain a   element defining the content provider with the authority causing the conflict.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
​<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<queries>
<intent>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:scheme="https"/>
</intent>
</queries>
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="48.0.0"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="false"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

​For reference, here is my app.json

```
{
"expo": {
"name": "Streetlight",
"slug": "streetlight",
"scheme": "streetlight",
"version": "2.0.9",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"splash": {
"image": "./assets/splash.png",
"resizeMode": "cover",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"updates": {
"fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
"**/*"
],
"ios": {
"supportsTablet": true,
"bundleIdentifier": "com.app.p1591CD",
"buildNumber": "15"
},
"android": {
"adaptiveIcon": {
"foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
"backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
},
"package": "com.app.p1591CD",
"versionCode": 6
},
"web": {
"favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
},
"extra": {
"eas": {
"projectId": "7620aadc-3df1-4e99-ae79-314bc570212d"
}
},
"hooks": {
"postPublish": [
{
"file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
"config": {
"organization": "chicago-coalition-fo-6f4680583",
"project": "streetlight-chicago"
}
}
]
},
"plugins": [
"expo-localization",
[
"expo-location",
{
"locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow Streetlight to use your location."
}
],
[
"@rnmapbox/maps",
{
"RNMapboxMapsImpl": "mapbox",
"RNMapboxMapsDownloadToken": "sk.eyJ1Ijoic3dhbHRlcjQ3IiwiYSI6ImNsbHBqNGZ0aTA1c2MzZG8wZjRsN3d1eHkifQ.MxWCRZIXNR5I8sGF2UOj9A"
}
],
"sentry-expo"
]
}
}
```

At a complete loss as there is not much helpful information out there. This is an Expo managed project, all ID's were auto generated by Expo so I am not clear as to why there would be a conflict.

Comment: Also happening to me. I haven’t found a solution yet.